# Building Classes to Construct Form Input Elements

Tags: php, forms, html, user-input

I am in the early stages of building a series of classes which will construct various types of form-input controls in PHP. Here is sample of the beginning of my code, which will later construct a text input control:

```
<?php
class TextInput {
//These properties are reqiured, and are defined on an as-needed basis
  public $name;

//These properties are optional, but can be defined on an as-needed basis
  public $disabled = false;
  public $maxLength = false;
  public $readOnly = false;
  public $size = false;
  public $type = "text";

//New to HTML5
  public $autoComplete = "off";
  public $autoFocus = false;
  public $listSuggestionArray = false;
  public $max = false;
  public $min = false;
  public $multiple = false; //Works for "email" type only
  public $pattern = false;
  public $placeHolder = false;
  public $required = false;

  public function __construct() {
  //Nothing to do!
  }

//Build the text input control
  public function build() {

  }
}
?>
```

As you can see, this class is already quite large, even though it doesn't do anything! My main question is, should I continue to build these classes to handle textareas, file inputs, etc..., considering that it would obviously put more of a load on the server to generate these?

As far as I can tell here are the pros and cons:

**Pros**:

- Very easy to instantiate later, as opposed to manually writing in HTML every time.
- Providing default values from a database, when they are available, will be a snap. For example, this class could listen when a particular form is being updated, and supply previously entered values from a database with one additional instance variable.
- Provide fallback for HTML5 input types (such as "color") whenever this input control is run on a non-HTML5 complaint browser.
- Other form input types could change depending on their options. For example, an additional instance variable for a textarea could tell client-side JavaScript to convert it into a WYSIWYG editor.

**Con**:

- A bit more of a load on the server to create the HTML for these elements, especially if there are many of them used on a single page.

Taking these into consideration, should I use this route, or revert to writing them out manually in HTML?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This seems to be better fitting for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is that you could at least use some inheritance (most of these elements will have a `name` attribute for example).

Comment: I agree. Thanks for reviewing the code! I just started writing it though. :) In the end, I'll be extending a `protected` base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this could be a good approach if you're wanting to also tie your input objects in with something else.  Like say, a validation/message response where your validation object passes data off to your input helper.  This should allow an 'easy' way to provide some user functionality in your forms.

If you **aren't** looking to incorporate some other functionality into this class at some point and you just want to spit out some HTML, and are worried about performance, you should just type it out raw.

**A suggestion**

With your current strategy you're gonna wind up copying a lot of things over and over.  When you want to create a `password` input or a `textarea` you'll wind up copying a lot of these same variables!

What you could do as an alternative is create a class that your form generator objects can extend from that provide some general functionality/properties for the appropriate types of HTML elements.  Obviously I couldn't even begin to tell you how to incorporate this into your own strategy without knowing a bigger picture of what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it.

Comment: Thanks Charles, for your input! I'm relieved to know that that wasn't just a crazy idea that no one should ever do. I appreciate your detailed explanation and helpful hints! Points up and answer accepted!